# Why is the user redirected to the login screen?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I would like to know why is my client redirected to the identity server.

I take the following steps:

1. Get redirected to the identity server to login.
2. Login and redirect back to client.
3. Use the app.
4. Stop using it.
5. Open the app after 12+ hours.
6. Get redirected to the login screen.
7. Scratch my head.

At this point the identity server, client and api are deployed to shared hosting provider, and I am using EF to store config and operations.

**Identity Server Configuration**

```cs
        services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Authentication.CookieSlidingExpiration = true;
            options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        }) 
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            })
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
            });


        services.AddAuthentication("custom")
            .AddCookie("custom", options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "custom";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            });

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddFacebook(options =>
            {
                options.AppId = "1";
                options.AppSecret = "2";
            });
```

**Client in Config.cs**

```cs
 new Client
 {
     ClientId = "mvc-client",
     ClientName = "Mvc Client",
     AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

     RequireConsent = false,

     ClientSecrets =
    {
       new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },

    RedirectUris = { $"{address}signin-oidc" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { $"{address}Client/" },

    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "api"
    },

        RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly,
        RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,
        SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = (3600 * 24 * 30),

        IdentityTokenLifetime = (60 * 15),
        AccessTokenLifetime = 300,

        AllowOfflineAccess = true,
 }
```

**MVC Client Configuration**

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
     {
         options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
     })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

        options.Authority = $"{_config["Server"]}";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.ClientId = "mvc-client";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";

        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

        options.Scope.Add("api");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
            RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
        };
    });
```

**Token Renew Service Filter**

```cs
var accessToken = await context.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
var introspectionClient = new IntrospectionClient(_ipoint, "api", "api_secret");
var response = await introspectionClient.SendAsync(new IntrospectionRequest { Token = accessToken });

if (!response.IsActive)
{
    var issuer = _config["Server"].ToLower();

    var client = new DiscoveryClient(issuer);
    client.Policy.RequireHttps = false;
    var disco = await client.GetAsync();

    if (disco.IsError) throw new Exception(disco.Error);

    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "mvc-client", "secret");

    var rt = await context.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token");
    var tokenResult = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(rt);

    if (!tokenResult.IsError)
    {
        var info = await context.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Cookies");

        var old_id_token = await context.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
        var new_access_token = tokenResult.AccessToken;
        var new_refresh_token = tokenResult.RefreshToken;

        var tokens = new List<AuthenticationToken>();
        tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken { Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken, Value = old_id_token });
        tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken { Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken, Value = new_access_token });
        tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken { Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken, Value = new_refresh_token });

        var expiresAt = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tokenResult.ExpiresIn);
        tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken { Name = "expires_at", Value = expiresAt.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) });


        info.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);
        await context.HttpContext.SignInAsync("Cookies", info.Principal, info.Properties);
    }
    else
    {
        await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
    }
}

await next();
```

**Note:** the cookie middle-ware I am attempting to override on the IS doesn't work. (Example: I cannot see the 'custom' cookie in the developer tools after login)

So my logic is the refresh token is 30 days (and is sliding), the cookie on the client is 30 days (and is renewed in the service filter), that means the user should be able to return after up to 30 days and still be able to use the client with the redirect to the identity server.

I am trying to achieve as little logins as possible, so if the user is actively using the app, I would like for him to never be redirected to the login page.

What I think happens is that the cookie is somehow lost and the `[Authorize]` attribute is called before my filter, hence the redirect happening. I am not sure if the `id_token` expiry can cause the redirect, enlighten me please.

Things I though can cause this issue:

1. I am missing something hence I am here.
2. The client app is going to sleep and the cookie is lost. I decided to rule this out since the app loads up pretty fast after a day of not using. (But then again...)
3. Has to do something with the cookie override not working. Then I though it's not causing it since the operations are in the database.

Comment: So that I am sure i understand your question.  You are trying to enable remember me so that the user doesn't have to login on the same machine for a month?

Comment: I want to understand why the refresh token inside the cookie in the mvc client isn't used to retrieve a new access token. Partly I understand that the client is no longer authenticated and I suspect its because of the way I configured the cookie. Not sure if that has anything to do with 'remeber me'.

Comment: Your mixing up authentication and authorization.   Refresh token just grants you access to a users data (authorization).  You could use it in the back end to request an access token and access the data.   However when the user navigates to your website they still need to be authenticated with a login and password.  Which has nothing to do with the fact that your application has authorization to access their data.  That being said you can set the authentication cookie so that the user wont have to login again on the same pc using a remember me type functionality it just sets a longer cookie.

Comment: @DaImTo so I have tried the remember me functionality on the IdentityServer, unfortunately the user still redirected to the client and is prompted to login, I expected it to at least remember the user that's logged in. The session does persist through browser being closed.

Comment: I have remember me enabled on my system with a 14 day cookie.   When i come back the next day it does not request access.

Comment: @DaImTo Would you mind showing how you set it up, perhaps I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hosting service I was using was refreshing it's app pool at 4:00am every day so the machine key was being dropped.

Storing the machine key in the file system was the solution:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName("Server")
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(_config["MachineKeys"]));
```

**Warning**: This solution doesn't encrypt the keys which it should with a x509 cert.